# Existence of small projective dimensioned modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, modules, dimension-theory

Suppose $A$ is a (if necessary unital) associative ring and $I$ is a left ideal in $A$. Let $\operatorname{pd}(M)$ denote the projective dimension of a left $A$-module $M$.

Then do either of the following exist:

1. $M\in \space _A\mathrm{Mod}$ such that $ \infty >\operatorname{pd}(M)\geq \operatorname{pd}(M/IM)$ and $M\neq 0$?
2. $N\in \space _A\mathrm{Mod}$ such that for all $J \lhd A$, the equation $\infty >\operatorname{pd}(N)\
   \geq \operatorname{pd}(N/JN)$ holds and $N\neq 0$?

Comment: If $A=\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$ and $I=\mathbb (x)/(x^2)$, then neither exists.

Comment: Sorry my inequalities were inverted; the question is now edited, thanks.

Comment: I think my example still works. Krull dimension of $A$ is zero, so the only modules with finite projective dimension are the projective modules. You are asking for a module $M$ with both $M$ and $M/IM$ projective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a commutative local artinian ring which is not a field, and $I \neq 0$ is the maximal ideal in $A$, then no such modules exist.

In this case every $A$-module has projective dimension $0$ or $\infty$, see for instance
(Bass, Hyman. [Finitistic dimension and a homological generalization of semi-primary rings](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-095-03/S0002-9947-1960-0157984-8/S0002-9947-1960-0157984-8.pdf)). By a theorem of Kaplansky, any projective module over a local ring is free.

Suppose $M$ is a non-zero $A$-module with $\operatorname{pd} (M)=0$. Since $I$ is nilpotent, we cannot have $IM=M$. Then $M/IM$ is a non-zero module annihilated by $I$, so it cannot be free. Therefore $\operatorname{pd} (M/IM)=\infty$.